# Why is my Child Div ignoring it's parent?

Tags: html, css

I have created a skills section using a series of divs. Basically when I set the child div to 100% width, it should be 100% width of the parent element right? But for some reason it is exceeding it. I don't understand why.

[image]

Here is my HTML and CSS so you can get a full understanding of what is going on:

```css
aside {
  background-color: #5abbd8;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0px 5%;
}

.skills-title {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.skill-points {
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.point-container {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.points {
  background-color: #FED36E;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.html {
  width: 70%;
}

.css {
  width: 60%;
}

.js {
  width: 30%;
}

.skill-level-indicator {
  width: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: -23px
}

.skill-percent {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  top: -34px;
  right: 0px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2 class="skills-title">Skills</h2>
    <div class="skill-info">
      <p>I am currently studying a Tech-degree in Front-End Web Development with Team Treehouse. The degree covers HTML CSS and JavaScript. I am now in the process of completing my second project out of 12.</p>
      <p>Below is a list of my skill levels within the coding languages I am learning.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- SKILL LEVEL INDICATORS -->
    <div class="skill-points">
    
      <p>HTML</p>
      <div class="point-container">
        <div class="points html">
          <img src="images/Skill-Level-Percent.png" alt="Skill-Level-Indicator" class="skill-level-indicator" />
          <p class="skill-percent">70%</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p>CSS</p>
      <div class="point-container">
        <div class="points css">
          <img src="images/Skill-Level-Percent.png" alt="Skill-Level-Indicator" class="skill-level-indicator" />
          <p class="skill-percent">60%</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p>JavaScript</p>
      <div class="point-container">
        <div class="points js">
          <img src="images/Skill-Level-percent.png" alt="Skill-Level-Indicator" class="skill-level-indicator diy" />
          <p class="skill-percent">30%</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: for the inner/ child div, could you try:  width: 50%;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 100% wide **and** has a 25 pixel margin.

So if the container is 200px wide, then it will runs from the 25px point to the 225px point.

Leave the width at `auto` if you want the width to fill whatever space is left after margins, borders and padding are accounted for.

Comment: That was it! I just removed the 100% width and now it works. There's me trying to do something clever, haha. Thanks so much!